# Keep aspect ratio of vertical aligned image in flex box

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

```
img{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

The full code can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZSSVt/

I want the image to "auto-fit" inside its div container, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Y3S/ (but vertically aligned).

Right now the kitten gets squished when the image is resized. How to fix that?

Comment: First of all, shame on you for squishing kittens, second of all, I really can't see where your problem is. Your aspect ratio seems fine to me

Comment: I don't see the problem either. Example 1 and Example 2 behave the same way except for vertical alignment.

Comment: Try making the window smaller than the image and you`ll see that the image doesn't get resized evenly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSSVt/3/)

Try wrapping the image in another div. `<img>` elements behave differently than `<div>` elements when `width` and `height` are applied.

For example `width: 100%` applied to `<img>` means that the image element will have the same width as the source picture. If you apply `width: 100%` to `<div>`, it would have the same width as the first parent with defined width.

Thus, your desired html will be:

```
<div class='box'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

With corresponding css for `wrapper` div:

```
div.wrapper {max-height:100%;}
```